# Error only appears in release mode and not in debug mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

Everything is working fine in debug mode but when I run the application in release mode, it produces this screen:
[image: 1]

and when I try hosting the application on firebase, I get this screen:
[image: 2]

I am not sure how to handle this error as there is not much info on this issue. But based on the "No firebase app" error, i think that the error might be in my main.dart.

## main.dart

```
void main() {
  assert(() {
    fb.initializeApp(
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
    );

    return true;
  }());

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = GeneralBlocDelegate();

  runApp(MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider<UserRepository>(
            builder: (context) => UserRepository()),
      ],
      child: MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
        BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          builder: (context) => AuthBloc(
              userRepository: RepositoryProvider.of<UserRepository>(context))
            ..add(AppStarted()),
        ),
      ], child: App())));
}
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>my website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script src="/__/firebase/7.2.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.2.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/7.2.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

## pubspec.yaml

```
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  firebase: ^6.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^1.0.0
  equatable: ^0.6.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1: Using `assert()` function to initialize app**

You are calling the `fb.initializeApp()` method inside the `assert()` method which will not be called in the release build. `assert` method is useful during development to add some additional checks. It should not contain or be used to handle, any functional/business logic. Check [this](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert) section of the dart language tour. It states that assert method is ignored in production mode.

> In production code, assertions are ignored, and the arguments to assert aren’t evaluated.

**Problem 2: Missing asset information in `pupspec.yaml`**

In your `index.html` I see you are trying to load some `.js` files like this `/__/firebase/init.js`. Flutter build will not keep this in the build folder unless you mark it as an asset in your `pubspec.yaml`.

Assuming you placed all your `.js` files you need for your application in a folder named `/js/init.js` like the following.

> In my case I have `js/` folder parallel to the `lib/`. This is my choice but you can choose which way you want it.

[image]

You need an entry like this in your `pubspec.yaml`.

```yaml
assets:
  - js/init.js
  - js/firebase-app.js
```

**OR**
Just include the entire folder like this.

```yaml
assets:
  - js/
```

The same applies for all the assets like images, data json etc... Check this [reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) for more details.

**Possible Problem 3: Incorrectly referring local `.js` file in Index.html**

In your index.html you are trying to load some local `.js` file as mentioned earlier. I think you should load these files as shown below if you follow my suggested folder structure. You should probably edit it based on your own choice.

```html
<script src="assets/js/init.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

<script src="assets/js/firebase-app.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Hope his helps. Happy Fluttering.

Comment: I removed the `assert` and the error in release mode is the same as when i host it and did not change when i host it again. I'm not sure if the problem is with my "index.html" so i add that part in the question

Comment: First of you should import all external scripts before importing the `main.dart.js` or at least defer the load. 

Next make sure your external scripts are loaded. You can check this by accessing the `fb` object in your browser console. Also I see you are trying to load the same scripts from a folder. In this case you should make you add them in the `assets` section of your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: I tried importing all external scripts before `main.dart.js` and also tried initialising firebase from `index.html`. it doesnt work, it produced the red error screen with no error message.
In the browser console the error is this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and `Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'minified:aF<void>'`

Comment: You shall check which resource didn't load...if its a javascript file then you have an issue with your `pubspec.yaml` can you post that as well.. ?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to pre-load the javascript throught the `pubspec.yaml`. I have uploaded my `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer to reflect the information you gave. Hope it solves your issue.