# Flutter - Bundle assets with web plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

I'm adding web support to a Flutter plugin which doesn't follow the federated style. I have followed [this link](https://medium.com/flutter/how-to-write-a-flutter-web-plugin-5e26c689ea1) and created a new project for the web plugin.

I need to bundle some JavaScript files with my plugin. I tried placing them on the `lib/` folder and referencing them from the generated HTML (using `dart:html`) as `packages/my_plugin/jsfile.js`.

This works perfectly fine on debug builds, but it doesn't on release builds.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58593348/3043944) i wrote sometime ago. I am sure it works for normal flutter web projects. Meanwhile I will check about the plugin article you shared.

Comment: I have tried it, but with no luck whatsoever